# How to read JSON data from Kafka and store to HDFS with Spark structued streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to read JSON messages from Kafka and store them in HDFS with spark structured streaming.

I followed the example [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) and when my code looks like this:

```py
df = spark \
  .read \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2") \
  .option("subscribe", "topic1") \
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
df.writeStream.format("json").option("checkpointLocation", "some/hdfs/path").start(/data")
```

Then I get rows with binary values in hdfs.

```
{"value":"BINARY DATA","topic":"test_hdfs2","partition":0,"offset":3463075,"timestamp":"2018-07-24T20:51:33.655Z","timestampType":0}
```

These rows are continually written as expected, but in the binary format.

I found this post:

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html

and I'm trying to implement this example:

```py
schema = StructType().add("a", IntegerType()).add("b", StringType())
df.select( \
  col("key").cast("string"),
  from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema))
```

But here I get an odd behvaiur. I have a small file written to hdfs with multiple empty json rows - {}

and very quickly the jobs fails with the following exception:

```
18/07/24 22:25:47 ERROR datasources.FileFormatWriter: Aborting job
null. java.lang.IllegalStateException:
hdfs://SOME_PATH/_spark_metadata/399.compact doesn't exist when
compacting batch 409 (compactInterval: 10)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:174)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:172)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.foreach(NumericRange.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.compact(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.add(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ManifestFileCommitProtocol.commitJob(ManifestFileCommitProtocol.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.addBatch(FileStreamSink.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:477)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:475)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:474)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
18/07/24 22:25:47 ERROR streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Query [id =
4f6c4ebc-f330-4697-b2db-7989b93dfba3, runId =
57575397-9fda-4370-9dcb-4550ae1576ec] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.addBatch(FileStreamSink.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:477)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:475)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:474)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
hdfs://SOME_PATH/_spark_metadata/399.compact doesn't exist when
compacting batch 409 (compactInterval: 10)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:174)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:172)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.foreach(NumericRange.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.compact(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.add(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ManifestFileCommitProtocol.commitJob(ManifestFileCommitProtocol.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
        ... 17 more
```

Any idea how to implement this in the right way?

Comment: You did run the selectExpr, but you have not assigned to df after running. Could it be about that? Please try this: `df = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")`

Answer (score 0):

If you see the error  ( 399.compact doesn't exist when compacting batch 409 (compactInterval: 10) its clearly saying error is due to its not finding the compact folder . Basically in spark structured streaming every batch run creates a .compact folder under _spark_metadata and to prevent the overhead of huge number of compact files from the past runs,periodically it tries to merge these files.

I think the default is every 10 batches it try to compact.So here when its running batch 409 and try to compact its not finding the previous one and failing. One option is to set . This is not really a business error and only spark bookkeeping error and to prevent your application from terminating add below `failOnDataLoss` to false.

```
spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", conf.servers)
      .option("subscribe", conf.topics)

      .option("failOnDataLoss",false)
```

Increase the compaction interval using the below property

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.fileSink.log.cleanupDelay", 60000)
```